# Load 32 or 64 bit dll with Java 32bit on 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I am attempting to load a compiled 32 bit or 64 bit DLL file with my Java code running under JRE 1.7 32bit on a Windows 7 64bit.  The DLL is named RecorderWindowsIA32.dll (32 bit) or RecorderWindowsAMD64.dll (64 bit) respectfully.

Both Fail respectfully:

*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: RecorderWindowsIA32 (.\RecorderWindowsIA32.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )*

*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: RecorderWindowsAMD64 (.\RecorderWindowsAMD64.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )*

Now, if I use a 1.7 JDK 64 bit (I haven't tried JRE 64bit) on my Windows 7 64bit, my code is able to load and use the 64 bit RecorderWindowsAMD64.dll.

I do not have a setup with a 32 bit machine and 32 bit JRE to test if RecorderWindowsIA32.dll will load.

**So my question I guess would be is it impossible to load/use a DLL with Java running a 32 bit JRE on a Windows 7 64 bit?**  If not, what am I doing wrong?  I have multiple Javas installed on my machine.  Possibly some of the paths are crossed?

Comment: There are restrictions what kind of process can load what DLL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx A 32 bit JRE can load a 32 bit DLL under a 64 bit windows, but you have to make sure you're not accidentally using an installed 64 bit JRE

Comment: I would guess that the 32-bit DLL has a dependency on another DLL, and it is finding the 64-bit version of the dependency first.  Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) may help you identify which DLLs are actually being loaded.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for your help.  I compiled the DLL as IA64 with x86_IA64.  I thought that meant compiling 32 bit for some stupid reason.  Next time, I will research before just hacking away.